# Makefile generating file with same name but by two different rules

Tags: linux, makefile

I want to have makefile witch generate one file with two different rules. One for commend make aaa and another for make bbb.
I have two files:
1.c and 2.c
rule aaa need result.o generated from 1.c
and bbb need result.o generated from 2.c

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the GNU Make documentation:

> A "rule" appears in the makefile and
>   says when and how to remake certain
>   files, called the rule's "targets"
>   (most often only one per rule).  It
>   lists the other files that are the
>   "prerequisites" of the target, and
>   "commands" to use to create or update
>   the target.

That is, the purpose of make *rules* is to generate some *target* which usually *is* the result file from some operation - be it a stamp file signalling that a step has executed or an object file from a compilation.

What you want, generate a `result.o` target for 2 different dependencies is just not exactly what make is intended to do.

What you can do, is generate targets `1.o` and `2.o`, which than get symlinked to `result.o` in a higher-level rule. This means however, that rules `aaa` and `bbb` have to *depend* on `1.o` and `2.o` as they have to have *separate* targets (which coincidentally are the rule's names).